# Кнопка подписки на канал Youtube

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube

С помощью данных примеров: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services, пытался создать в своем приложении кнопку подписки на канал Youtube.

Использовал для этого следующую функцию:

```
-(void) subscription{

    NSString *channelId = @«MyChannelId»;
    NSString *api_Key = @«MY_IOS_API_KEY»;

    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=%@", api_Key];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken];
    NSLog(@"Access Token: %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken);

    [requestSerializer setValue: authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"snippet":@{
                                     @"resourceId":@{
                                             @"channelId":channelId,
                                             @"kind":@"youtube#channel"
                                             }
                                     }
                             };
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@«OK:»);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@«Faild:»);
    }];
}
```

После чего передаю, полученные значения:

```
- (void) receiveToggleAuthUINotification:(NSNotification *) notification {

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ToggleAuthUINotification"]) {
        [self subscriptionBtn];   
    }
}
```

Получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
error =     {
    code = 403;
    errors =         (
                    {
            domain = usageLimits;
            extendedHelp = "https://console.developers.google.com";
            message = "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.";
            reason = ipRefererBlocked;
        }
    );
    message = "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.";
};
```

Нет вариантов где напортачил?

Comment: мне кажется там довольно таки однозначное сообщение об ошибке